# TfLite Model always shows 0.5 as score in ESP32

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, esp32

I created a model to classify Cardboard/Paper or Plastic, I loaded the model as tflite in Google Colab and it worked as expected, but when I loaded it in the ESP32CAM (AI thinker) it predicts 0.5 for each label.
I consider that something in the implementation of the Neural network is wrong because it doesn't matter what I set in the input that the output is the same (I tried also not setting anything and the same)

I'm using MobilNet V2 from tensorflow (tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2)

**This is my NeuralNetwork.cpp** ( I also have a main.cpp where I implemented the camera and where I call classify_image())

```
#include "NeuralNetwork.h"
#include "model_160x120_data.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "esp_camera.h"


float* model_input_buffer = nullptr;
const int kArenaSize = 1900000;
NeuralNetwork::NeuralNetwork()
{
    error_reporter = new tflite::MicroErrorReporter();
    model = tflite::GetModel(garbageTfLite160x120_tflite);

    
    // This pulls in the operators implementations we need
    
    resolver = new tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<10>();

    resolver->AddAveragePool2D();
    resolver->AddConv2D(); //adentro de los parentesis: tflite::Register_CONV_2D_INT8()
    resolver->AddDepthwiseConv2D(); //adentro de los parentesis: tflite::Register_DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D_INT8()
    resolver->AddReshape();
    resolver->AddSoftmax(); //adentro de los parentesis: tflite::Register_SOFTMAX_INT8()
    resolver->AddAdd();
    resolver->AddPad();
    resolver->AddPadV2();
    resolver->AddMean();
    resolver->AddFullyConnected();


    tensor_arena = (uint8_t *) ps_malloc(kArenaSize); //esp32cam has psram -> ps_malloc (I tried with malloc but still getting 0.5 for each score) 
    if (!tensor_arena)
    {
        TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Could not allocate arena");
        return;
    }
    // Build an interpreter to run the model with.
    interpreter = new tflite::MicroInterpreter(
        model, *resolver, tensor_arena, kArenaSize, error_reporter);
    // Allocate memory from the tensor_arena for the model's tensors.
    TfLiteStatus allocate_status = interpreter->AllocateTensors();
    if (allocate_status != kTfLiteOk)
    {
        TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "AllocateTensors() failed");
        return;
    }
    size_t used_bytes = interpreter->arena_used_bytes();
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Used bytes by the model: %d\n", used_bytes);

    // Obtain pointers to the model's input and output tensors.
    input = interpreter->input(0);
    model_input_buffer = input->data.f;
    output = interpreter->output(0);

    int batch_size = input->dims->data[0];
    int h = input->dims->data[1];
    int w = input->dims->data[2];
    int channels = input->dims->data[3];
    Serial.print("\n ");
    Serial.print(batch_size);
    Serial.print("\n ");
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print("\n ");
    Serial.print(w);
    Serial.print("\n ");
    Serial.print(channels);
    Serial.print("\n ");
}


float NeuralNetwork::classify_image(camera_fb_t *fb) {
 
    Serial.println ("DIMS: ");
    Serial.println(input->dims->size);
    Serial.println("input-> bytes: ");
    Serial.println(input->bytes);
    
    int img_size = 120*160*3;
    for (int i=0; i < img_size; i++) {
        model_input_buffer[i] = fb->buf[i]/255.0;
    }


    if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->Invoke()) 
    {
        error_reporter->Report("Error");
    }
    
    TfLiteTensor* output = interpreter->output(0);
    Serial.println("output0: ");
    Serial.println(output->data.f[0]);
    Serial.println("output1: ");
    Serial.println(output->data.f[1]);
    Serial.println("output2: ");
    Serial.println(output->data.f[2]);
    return output->data.f[0];

}
```

**Output LOGS:**

```
Used bytes by the model: 1898436

batch_size: 1

h: 120

w: 160

channels: 3

DIMS: 4
input-> bytes:230400

output0: 0.50

output1: 0.50
```

**TFLITE Conversion in Python:**

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('/content/GarbageClassificator_2Labels')
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
converter.inference_input_type = tf.float32
converter.inference_output_type = tf.float32

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

**TF LITE MODEL EXECUTION IN PYTHON:**

```
# Load TF LITE MODEL
ruta_modelo_tflite = "garbageTflite_160x120.tflite"
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=ruta_modelo_tflite)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

print (input_details)
print (output_details)
predictions = []
for num in range (0, len(X_test)): //X_test was already normalized (x_test / 255) 
  input_data = np.array(X_test[num], dtype=np.float32)
  input_data = np.expand_dims(input_data, axis=0)

  interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

  interpreter.invoke()

  output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

  predictions.append (np.argmax(output_data))
```

**INPUT DETAILS:**
`[{'name': 'serving_default_input_1:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 160, 120,   3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ -1, 160, 120,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]`

**OUTPUT DETAILS:**
`[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0', 'index': 100, 'shape': array([1, 2], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1,  2], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]`

**PYTHON RESULTS:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTVMD.png)

I expected to have a probability distribution in:

```
Serial.println(output->data.f[0]);
Serial.println(output->data.f[1]);
```

Not always 0.5

I would really appreciate any help/clue. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: I found out that I have TF version 2.13.0 in Google Colab and 2.3.4 in my C++ project. Working to move them to the same version and re-check

Comment: Once I updated the TF version in my C++ project to a newer one, it started working :)
I guess some ops were not available in the previous version but I didn't receive any warning or error about it